# Request XML from SUDS python

Tags: python, soap, suds

Is there any method to return the SOAP Request XML before triggering a call to SOAP method in Suds library?

The client.last_sent() returns request XML after triggered the call. But I want to see before triggering the call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible and seems to be used in different "fixer" implementations to take care of buggy servers. Basically you should write a `MessagePlugin` and implement the `sending` method.